# React Native: Compare app versions and return major or minor strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to compare two versions, the local, that is installed on the user's device, and the version, that is available in app stores. Currently, I am trying to achieve the desired result using library [compareVersions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compare-versions). That works great, returns string 'new' if the remote version is greater. But I need a bit more other output that I am trying to get, for example, if local version is `1.0.5` and remote is `1.0.6` (changes the last number), then I need to return 'minor', and if local version is `1.0.5` and remote is `1.1.0` (changes the middle number and last), then return 'major'. The main idea for me is to get a different output in these cases, so based on version check I can update the UI accordingly. Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: So you are trying to return the smallest part of the versioning that is still the same? If the only the *patch* version has changed, you want to return "minor". If the *minor* version is changed, you want to return "major". What should be returned if the *major* version has changed? And what should be returned if the two versions are equal?

Comment: Yes, you got it right. _path_ is as "minor", _minor_ is as "major". If the _major_ part changes, return "superMajor" and if are equal, then return "equal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote once a function that compares two versions, you could adapt it to instead of returning a boolean return a string:

```js
const DEFAULT_VERSION = '0.0.0';

export const isLatestGreaterThanCurrent = ({ latest = DEFAULT_VERSION, current = DEFAULT_VERSION } = {}) => {
  const [latestMajor, latestMinor, latestPatch] = latest.split('.').map((s) => parseInt(s, 10));
  const [currentMajor, currentMinor, currentPatch] = current.split('.').map((s) => parseInt(s, 10));

  return (
    latestMajor > currentMajor ||
    (latestMajor === currentMajor && latestMinor > currentMinor) ||
    (latestMajor === currentMajor && latestMinor === currentMinor && latestPatch > currentPatch)
  );
};
```

and of course, its tests:

```js
import { isLatestGreaterThanCurrent } from '../isLatestGreaterThanCurrent';
import each from "jest-each";

describe('isLatestGreaterThanCurrent', () => {
  each([
    // [latest, current]
    ['0.0.0', '0.0.0'],
    ['0.0.0', '0.0.1'],
    ['0.0.1', '0.1.0'],
    ['0.1.0', '0.1.0'],
    ['0.1.0', '0.1.1'],
    ['0.1.1', '1.0.0'],
    ['1.0.0', '1.0.0'],
    ['1.0.0', '1.0.1'],
    ['1.0.1', '1.1.0'],
    ['1.1.0', '1.1.0'],
    ['1.1.0', '1.1.1'],
    ['1.1.1', '1.1.1'],
  ]).test('latest %s is NOT greater than current %s', (latest, current) => {
    expect(isLatestGreaterThanCurrent({latest, current})).toBeFalsy();
  });

  each([
    // [latest, current]
    ['0.0.1', '0.0.0'],
    ['0.1.0', '0.0.1'],
    ['0.1.1', '0.1.0'],
    ['1.0.0', '0.1.1'],
    ['1.0.1', '1.0.0'],
    ['1.1.0', '1.0.0'],
    ['1.1.0', '1.0.1'],
    ['1.1.1', '1.1.0'],
  ]).test('latest %s is greater than current %s',  (latest, current) => {
    expect(isLatestGreaterThanCurrent({latest, current})).toBeTruthy();
  })
});
```